# I'm writing a program for homework but I can't get it to work

Tags: python

One of the homework programs I have to write is a basic dnd thing where I input a monster strenght and use the randrange funtion as a dice roller. the issue is I can't get the part where it compares the rolled result and the input strength to see which is higher to work.
Here's the code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import random

input("monster strength")
monster_strength = input
rolled_num = random.randrange(20)+1``
print( "you rolled" ,rolled_num)
if rolled_num > monster_strength:
    print("you win")
else:
    print("you fail")
```

Comment: `monster_strength = int(input("Enter monster strength: "))`

Comment: Also don't import conditionally. Put the code inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, and the imports at the top.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Another thing - seems to me like using `random.randint(1, 20)` would've been better for you